# Function breaks on jQuery 3 from jQuery 2

Tags: jquery

I’ve got a code that works on jQuery 2 but breaks with jQuery 3.

I’ve narrowed it down to the following function:

```
_switchImage: function(imageId) {
  var $newImage = $( this.selectors.$productImageWrappers.selector + "[data-image-id='" + imageId + "']", this.$container );
  var $otherImages = $( this.selectors.$productImageWrappers.selector + ":not([data-image-id='" + imageId + "'])", this.$container );      
  $newImage.removeClass('hidden');
  $otherImages.addClass('hidden');
},
```

Any idea what’s wrong in this?

Comment: `.selector` was deprecated in 2011 and removed from v3 ... https://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: Thanks! Newbie here, any idea on how to rewrite this without .selector ?

Comment: I have some ideas but would really need to see more code context as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I managed to rewrite that function. It appears to be working, I’ll have to do more testing but I believe I got it.

```
_switchImage: function(imageId) {
  var $newImage = this.selectors.$productImageWrappers.filter('[data-image-id="' + imageId + '"]'); 
  var $allImages = this.selectors.$productImageWrappers.not($newImage);         

  $newImage.removeClass('hidden');
  $allImages.addClass('hidden');
},
```